# Possible to enforce type in this specific functional context?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I'm using lodash which has specific syntax, and I would like to enforce type using facebook flowtype. here is the code:

```
 let errorMessageBag = _.flow( objectWithFieldsToValidate, requiredFields, 
                             stringLengthValidationCheck, emailValidation)
 let result = errorMessageBag(fields, linkmodel())
```

I would like to enforce `errorMessageBag` call to pass the 2 parameters, fields and `linkmodel()`. For the sake of simplicity let's say I would like them to be `string,string`.

The flow arguments are the names of the functions that are just below. It's the first one `objectWithFieldsToValidate` that takes the 2 arguments, but if I type them it won't propagate. Anyway to resolve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy work around is to encapsulate errorMessageBag(fields, linkmodel()) into a function with easily typed parameters. So you end up calling that new function which return errorMessageBag(fields, linkmodel()) .

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
// assuming `void` is the return type of validation
let errorMessageBag: (x: string, y: string) => void = ...; 
let result = errorMessageBag(fields, linkmodel())
```